# Change 'show desktop' keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, desktop

I can show the desktop in Yosemite using <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>

However I would like to change it to something else. I've done this in the past but can't remember how, and can't find anything online for that matter.

Also when I look under System Preferences I see nothing relating to this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System Preferences → Mission Control → Show Desktop. Hold down a modifier key to affect which keys are shown.

[image]

You can also see more keyboard shortcut options through System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Mission Control → Show Desktop.

[image]